# Separating 'heart sound' from 'lung sound'

Tags: fft, filter-design, fourier-series, mfcc, periodic

I have audio files recorded from electronic stethoscope and in those files I want to filter out heart sounds and retain just the breathing sounds. How can I do this using just the **signal processing techniques**? Since I don't have clean data, can't apply machine learning.

Comment: Hi Hamza, this is too broad of a question. There are a multitude of algorithms aimed at this particular problem, which you can search the web for. [Here is a review](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27420021/). I suggest you try one or a few of them and come back here when you have specific questions!